# react - state gets set to null after button click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have my code:

```
function App() {
  const [refundData, setRefundData] = useState(Array<ICancellationRefundOptionModel>());
  const [grid, setGridData] = useState(Array<JSX.Element>());

  useEffect(() => {
    getFailedRequests()
  }, []);

  const getFailedRequests = async () => {
    const failedRefundData = await getRequestAsync("myApiUrl")
    setRefundData(failedRefundData);
    createTable(failedRefundData);
  }

  const createTable = (dataArray: Array<ICancellationRefundOptionModel>) => {
    const dataTable = dataArray.map(x => {
      return (<tr>
        <td>{x.customerId}</td>        
        <td><button onClick={() => handleOnClick(x)}>Process</button></td>
      </tr>
      )
    })
    setGridData(dataTable);
  }

  const handleOnClick = async (refund: ICancellationRefundOptionModel) => {
    await postRequestAsync(refund, "");
    const newGrid = refundData.filter((item) => item.customerId !== refund.customerId);

    createTable(newGrid);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Customer Id</th>            
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {grid}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This makes a call to my api where I get my data to populate a table. What I'm trying to do is after a user clicks one of the Process buttons, that customer is processed so the row will be removed from my table, but the issue is when I click on one of the buttons, the "refundData" state is empty, even though it has a value after the page loads (I put a console.log in my getFailedRequests method and it has all the data it should).

I'm not really understanding why refundData is being set to empty.

Comment: This is why you really should ***not*** store React components in state, you've closed over the initial undefined `refundData` state value in the `handleOnClick` callback attached to a button of some JSX that you stored in `grid` in `createTable`. Don't enclose state in callbacks and then save the instantiated JSX into state, just store the data and render it out normally to JSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Drew Reese in the comment - you shouldn't be storing the grid as a state object. Instead, just render it on the fly once the `refundData` has been returned.

If you simplify the component as follows, not only is it easier to understand, but it should fix up your closure problems. Note that the `handleOnClick` event handler now changes the `refundData` state after the click event - the net effect of this is that it will cause the table to render without the row that has been removed.

```
function App() {
  const [refundData, setRefundData] = useState<ICancellationRefundOptionModel[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFailedRequests();
  }, []);

  const getFailedRequests = async () => {
    const failedRefundData = await getRequestAsync("myApiUrl")
    setRefundData(failedRefundData);
  }

  const handleOnClick = async (refund: ICancellationRefundOptionModel) => {
    await postRequestAsync(refund, "");
    setRefundData(prev => prev.filter((item) => item.customerId !== refund.customerId));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Customer Id</th>            
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {refundData?.length && refundData.map(x => (
            <tr>
                <td>{x.customerId}</td>        
                <td><button onClick={() => handleOnClick(x)}>Process</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```